# How to timeout a future computation after a timeLimit?

Tags: dart, dart-html

When defining a Future as follows:

```
Future<HttpRequest> httpRequest =  HttpRequest.request(url,
      method: method, requestHeaders: requestHeaders);
```

I want to handle a timeout after 5 secondes. I'm writing my code like this :

```
httpRequest.timeout(const Duration (seconds:5),onTimeout : _onTimeout());
```

Where my timeout function is :

```
_onTimeout() => print("Time Out occurs");
```

According to the [Future timeout() method documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/134942/dart-async/Future/timeout.html) , If `onTimeout` is omitted, a timeout will cause the returned future to complete with a `TimeoutException`. But With my code , my method `_onTimeout()` is  properly called (but immediately, not after 5 seconds) and I always get a

> TimeException after 5 seconds... (TimeoutException after 0:00:05.000000: Future not completed )

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change this line

```
httpRequest.timeout(const Duration (seconds:5),onTimeout : _onTimeout());
```

to

```
httpRequest.timeout(const Duration (seconds:5),onTimeout : () => _onTimeout());
```

or just pass a reference to the function (without the `()`)

```
httpRequest.timeout(const Duration (seconds:5),onTimeout : _onTimeout);
```

This way the closure that calls `_onTimeout()` will be passed to `timeout()`.
In the former code the result of the `_onTimeout()` call will be passed to `timeout()`

Comment: Or it can simply be `onTimeout : _onTimeout` (without parenthesis).

Answer (score 14):

```
Future.await[_doSome].then((data){
    print(data);
    }).timeout(Duration(seconds: 10));
```

Comment: Brilliant. I didnt know that timeouts was built into Future's. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Using async/await style. You can add `.timeout` to any `Future` you are awaiting.

```
final result = await InternetAddress
   .lookup('example.com')
   .timeout(
      Duration(seconds: 10),
      onTimeout: () => throw TimeoutException('Can\'t connect in 10 seconds.'),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop any `Future` by timeout one can use [timeout()](https://api.dart.dev/be/176281/dart-async/Future/timeout.html). There are two examples:

1. Throw exception after timeout

```dart
  final someHardTaskFuture = Future.delayed(const Duration(hours: 1), () => 42);
  final newFutureWithTimeoutAndException = someHardTaskFuture.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3));
```

2. Returns default value (11) on timeout

```dart
  final someHardTaskFuture = Future.delayed(const Duration(hours: 1), () => 42);
  final newFutureWithTimeoutAndDefaultValue = someHardTaskFuture
      .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 3), onTimeout: () => 11);
  print(await newFutureWithTimeoutAndDefaultValue);
```