# Check whether there is an Internet connection available on Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, internet-connection, flutter-plugin

I have a network call to be executed. But before doing that I need to check whether the device have internet connectivity.

This is what i have done so far:

```
  var connectivityResult = new Connectivity().checkConnectivity();// User defined class
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
        connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {*/
    this.getData();
    } else {
      neverSatisfied();
    }
```

Above method is not working.

Answer (score 402, accepted):

The [connectivity](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-) plugin states in its docs that it only provides information if there is a network connection, but not if the network is connected to the Internet

> Note that on Android, this does not guarantee connection to Internet. For instance, the app might have wifi access but it might be a VPN or a hotel WiFi with no access.

You can use

```
import 'dart:io';
...
try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    print('connected');
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  print('not connected');
}
```

### Update

The [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-) package is deprecated. Use the official Flutter Community [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package instead.

Comment: I am getting error "isNotEmpty is not declared inside InternetAddress"

Comment: Ups, I deleted the code locally already, but I think it should be `result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty`. Sorry for that.

Comment: I'm getting errors on this code as well on ` on SocketException catch(_) ` . Says `on ` is undefined.

Comment: Please fix the curly brackets: you have 3 `{` and 2 `}`.

Comment: Can this be achieved in background? Like I have a queue of tasks pending for execution and waiting for internet but the app is closed?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager allows to execute code in the background (at least on Android, it's a bit more difficult on iOS). I don't know if it allows to access plugins though.

Comment: Please note that google.com is not accessible inside in China and as such the example will hang if used in China. In order to expand your audience please avoid using google.com and use example.com instead.

final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');

Comment: This does not work for me `if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty)` returns true when there's wifi but not internet connection.

Comment: @Denn Which url did you use?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I used `google.com` and also tried my own api url. does it matter which one I use?

Comment: @Denn Even I didn't used to think if url matters, but someone said `google.com` doesn't work in China so I asked you.

Comment: var result = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity(); giving me error like "ConnectivityService: Neither user 11177 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE., null)" Can anybody help ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing might help. The manifest example shows how to add the permission. Search the page for .ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Comment: @LOG_TAG can you please elaborate?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sorry, without using  connectivity: ^0.4.3+2 via firebase flutter sdk https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities via dart version of database.getReference(".info/connected"); is possible?

Comment: Is it possible to create an app similar to Internet Speed Meter using Flutter?

Comment: There isn't really a limitation on what you can do with Flutter except perhaps things like pure background apps and launcher plugins. You might need to call out to native APIs for certain things though.

Comment: hey guys,it's working when we have connected it with wifi..but wifi has no internet it's still showing connected...any solution for this issue?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can I configure the timeout time? In my tests your code takes about 2.5 minutes to report that the user is disconnected.

Comment: @mFeinstein if yo do not use `await` you get a `Future` where you can set a timeout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897140/how-to-timeout-a-future-computation-after-a-timelimit

Comment: Oh, yes, I completely forgot about this! Actually I think I can keep using `await`, I can just append `.timeout` after `lookup()`.

Comment: Is there any way to detect network state change without using connectivity plugin?

Comment: @SagarV is there a specific reason you don't want to use the plugin?

Comment: This code works for me but some users in my production app complaint that they are "not connected" if they use WIFI (while they are "connect" if they if they use cellular data). What could it be the culprit?

Comment: For some reason, the code works in the emulator but not in a real device. Has anybody ever experienced that ?

Comment: @BarnettTemwaMsiska "does not work" is something you should generally avoid when asking for support. It could be that your computer has no power to the CIA hacked your computer and installed spyware. If you need guidance, provide proper information about what you tried and how the result is different from what you expected. Perhaps better to create a new question with the information required to reproduce.

Comment: Since I have users in China, I realized that google.com is banned in China. So I advise you to use another site to check if the user has an internet connection. Personally I use 'example.com'

Comment: I cannot catch SocketException

Comment: just curious, 
example.com uses insecure http connection. wouldn't this be a problem in production when you disable insecure connections?

Comment: I doesn't connect, it just tries to resolve the hostname. It assumes that it has a connection to the internet if it gets an IP.

Comment: This does not solve the issue in Flutter 2. As mentioned by Günter Zöchbauer
  the 1st time im offline its not able to resolve the hostname. But the 2nd time i guess it caches it and returns the address when u go offline

Comment: it wont work on Flutter Web as uses dart.io lib. 
data_connection_checker does not support null safety.
internet_connection_checker wont work on Flutter Web as well.
What can we do?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine

Comment: this always returns true for me

Comment: InternetAddress.lookup returns cached result after the first request to lookup example.com, even if you go offline.
There is an issue describing this behaviour - https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52156

Comment: I tried this and is unreliable, I think the problem is with connectivity_plus package.
Replaced the implementation with https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 134):

For anyone else who lands here I'd like to add on to Günter Zöchbauer's answer this was my solution for implementing a utility to know if there's internet or not regardless of anything else.

**Disclaimer:**

I'm new to both Dart and Flutter so this may not be the best approach, but would love to get feedback.

---

### Combining flutter_connectivity and Günter Zöchbauer's connection test

**My requirements**

I didn't want to have a bunch of repeated code anywhere I needed to check the connection and I wanted it to automatically update components or anything else that cared about the connection whenever there was a change.

#### ConnectionStatusSingleton

First we setup a Singleton. If you're unfamiliar with this pattern there's a lot of good info online about them. But the gist is that you want to make a single instance of a class during the application life cycle and be able to use it anywhere.

This singleton hooks into `flutter_connectivity` and listens for connectivity changes, then tests the network connection, then uses a `StreamController` to update anything that cares.

It looks like this:

```
import 'dart:io'; //InternetAddress utility
import 'dart:async'; //For StreamController/Stream

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

class ConnectionStatusSingleton {
    //This creates the single instance by calling the `_internal` constructor specified below
    static final ConnectionStatusSingleton _singleton = new ConnectionStatusSingleton._internal();
    ConnectionStatusSingleton._internal();

    //This is what's used to retrieve the instance through the app
    static ConnectionStatusSingleton getInstance() => _singleton;

    //This tracks the current connection status
    bool hasConnection = false;

    //This is how we'll allow subscribing to connection changes
    StreamController connectionChangeController = new StreamController.broadcast();

    //flutter_connectivity
    final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();

    //Hook into flutter_connectivity's Stream to listen for changes
    //And check the connection status out of the gate
    void initialize() {
        _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_connectionChange);
        checkConnection();
    }

    Stream get connectionChange => connectionChangeController.stream;

    //A clean up method to close our StreamController
    //   Because this is meant to exist through the entire application life cycle this isn't
    //   really an issue
    void dispose() {
        connectionChangeController.close();
    }

    //flutter_connectivity's listener
    void _connectionChange(ConnectivityResult result) {
        checkConnection();
    }

    //The test to actually see if there is a connection
    Future<bool> checkConnection() async {
        bool previousConnection = hasConnection;

        try {
            final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
            if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
                hasConnection = true;
            } else {
                hasConnection = false;
            }
        } on SocketException catch(_) {
            hasConnection = false;
        }

        //The connection status changed send out an update to all listeners
        if (previousConnection != hasConnection) {
            connectionChangeController.add(hasConnection);
        }

        return hasConnection;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

**Initialization**

First we have to make sure we call the initialize of our singleton. But only once.
This parts up to you but I did it in my app's `main()`:

```
void main() {
    ConnectionStatusSingleton connectionStatus = ConnectionStatusSingleton.getInstance();
    connectionStatus.initialize();

    runApp(MyApp());

    //Call this if initialization is occuring in a scope that will end during app lifecycle
    //connectionStatus.dispose();   
}
```

**In `Widget` or elsewhere**

```
import 'dart:async'; //For StreamSubscription

...

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
    StreamSubscription _connectionChangeStream;

    bool isOffline = false;

    @override
    initState() {
        super.initState();

        ConnectionStatusSingleton connectionStatus = ConnectionStatusSingleton.getInstance();
        _connectionChangeStream = connectionStatus.connectionChange.listen(connectionChanged);
    }

    void connectionChanged(dynamic hasConnection) {
        setState(() {
            isOffline = !hasConnection;
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope somebody else finds this useful!

---

Example github repo: https://github.com/dennmat/flutter-connectiontest-example

Toggle airplane mode in the emulator to see the result

Comment: I put the first code in Main.dart and tried with a HomePage,but this trhows the following error Could not load source 'dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart': <source not available>.

Comment: There's likely another error and that's just the editor trying to open the file but it doesn't have access to it. I modified this example from my code to generalize it. May have broke something. I'll check when I'm back home. But if you look at the debug panel can you find the real error?

Comment: Tested the code and it's working for me I'd need more info to help out.

Comment: i tried now too,but it throws the same error,Could u please make a sample flutter app in github??

Comment: Ahh, ok I see it. So again for your future reference the error you're posting is just the editor trying to open the file where it think the error occured. The real error should be available in your editors debug console/stack trace panel. So I guess runApp returns I assumed it would run for the entirety of the programs life. Seeing as this is in the main the dispose isn't really necessary here so just remove `connectionStatus.dispose()` assuming you're setting it up in the `main()` like above. Will update post and link to github example.

Comment: now the error is gone,But the bugs are,when i swtich from one wifi to another Wifi it detects Actvie Internet Connection,but Stayign on the same Wifi,i turned of Internet,..it doesn't detect the changes,..

Comment: To just detect if wifi or cellular is being switched you only need flutter connectivity. This wrapper checks the connection after the switch occurs. But won't alert every network change. If you're using the emulator toggling airplane mode is the easiest way to lose internet connection. If you're on an actual device you'd have to make sure you weren't still connected to a mobile network with data.

Comment: my clear requirement is detecting LIVE ACTIVE INTERNET CONNECTION changes,like youtube and google go apps,but no solutions found for that,t tried streamiing http results,none of them helped

Comment: There's a few options for that, you can modify the above to use Timer to test frequently. Or just test frequently using the Timer utility. See: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html Another option is testing the connection before every request you send. Although seems like you may be looking for something like websockets. Anyway good luck

Comment: @dennmat widget displays as connected. when I open application while connection is off. Can you check that?

Comment: Aw it's likely due to the first check occurring before the component even exists and in my example it defaults to thinking it's online. Instead you could assign the default value of `isOffline` to `!mySingletonInstance.hasConnection`.

Comment: Is it really necessary to save _connectionChangeStream in the state? My linter shows a warning of: "The value of the field '_connectionChangeStream' isn't used."

Comment: Shouldn't we cancel the subscription in the widget's dispose() function? I see this is done in other StreamController examples like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788256/updating-data-in-flutter

Comment: I tried you GitHub repo. But it has a bug. first time application loading without connecting internet, showing "connected". How to fix this issue?

Comment: Nice implementation! Thanks to Dart's support for top-level variables, your singleton can be a lot simpler, though: `final connectionStatus = new ConnectionStatusSingleton.init();`

Comment: For WEB support, I replaced `dart.io` with [`dio`](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

Comment: hi, you are listening to connectivity changes and then checking the internet connectivity. but connection to internet might be lost while there is connectivity to existing source wifi or mobile.

Comment: I think we must cancel this line `_connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_connectionChange);` on `dispose`. Put this line in variable to call `.cancel()` later in `dispose` function.

Comment: make sure you put  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); as first line on main()

Comment: I tried the solution above but I keep getting an error as follows:

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value`

Which points to the error on listed
`_connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_connectionChange);`

Comment: @AashwiinRoghan Yea I had the same issue, this post seems old. I have updated with same logic. check below

Comment: the best solution

Comment: The connectivity package is deprecated. Use the connectivity_plus package instead.

Comment: hello, I followed your example and implemented it, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 126):

## Null Safe code:

- #### One time check:

  Create this method:

  ```dart
  Future<bool> hasNetwork() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      return result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  ```

  Usage:

  ```dart
  bool isOnline = await hasNetwork();
  ```
- #### Setting up a listener:

  Add the following dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

  ```
  connectivity_plus: ^2.0.2
  ```

  **Full code:**

  ```dart
  void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));

  class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
  }

  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    Map _source = {ConnectivityResult.none: false};
    final MyConnectivity _connectivity = MyConnectivity.instance;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _connectivity.initialise();
      _connectivity.myStream.listen((source) {
        setState(() => _source = source);
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      String string;
      switch (_source.keys.toList()[0]) {
        case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
          string = 'Mobile: Online';
          break;
        case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
          string = 'WiFi: Online';
          break;
        case ConnectivityResult.none:
        default:
          string = 'Offline';
      }

      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text(string)),
      );
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _connectivity.disposeStream();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }

  class MyConnectivity {
    MyConnectivity._();

    static final _instance = MyConnectivity._();
    static MyConnectivity get instance => _instance;
    final _connectivity = Connectivity();
    final _controller = StreamController.broadcast();
    Stream get myStream => _controller.stream;

    void initialise() async {
      ConnectivityResult result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
      _checkStatus(result);
      _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((result) {
        _checkStatus(result);
      });
    }

    void _checkStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
      bool isOnline = false;
      try {
        final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
        isOnline = result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
      } on SocketException catch (_) {
        isOnline = false;
      }
      _controller.sink.add({result: isOnline});
    }

    void disposeStream() => _controller.close();
  }
  ```

---

#### Screenshot:

[image]

<sub>Credit to : [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) and Günter Zöchbauer</sub>

Comment: via firebase, SDK is it possible?

Comment: @LOG_TAG You don't have to use Firebase for this.

Comment: Map _source = {ConnectivityResult.none: false};
Why you used "false" in here

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Thanks you! I used this method, But this method give me first time NoInternetConnection! Why first give me None? This is my debug print : 
connectivityResult.none
connectivityResult.wifi
connectivityResult.wifi.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad But this is not true. we should not wait.

Comment: @FarukAYDIN I have deleted all my comments, you can do that too.

Comment: How can i implement it for the whole application ?

Comment: @Rock : i just need to change at body scaffold similar like this,
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Internet")),
      body: string=="Offline" ? isNotConnected() : isConnected(),
    );

Comment: If you caught "no connection error" always, Add ""_source.clear(); before "setState(() => _source = source);"

Comment: I am using this code with a stream provider but isOnline is always returning true even if I disconnect my wi-fi.

Comment: Great! Im using the one tie check and initially I thought it wasnt working because it was always returning true with ethernet. Then I realised I need to put a real web address like `google.com`

Comment: is this solution tell us if wifi is connected but no internet ?

Comment: returns true even if the WiFi is connected but not has access to internet

Answer (score 45):

I found that just using the [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package was not enough to tell if the internet was available or not.  In Android it only checks if there is WIFI or if mobile data is turned on, it does not check for an actual internet connection .  During my testing, even with no mobile signal ConnectivityResult.mobile would return true.

With IOS my testing found that the connectivity plugin does correctly detect if there is an internet connection when the phone has no signal, the issue was only with Android.

The solution I found was to use the [data_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker) package along with the connectivity package.  This just makes sure there is an internet connection by making requests to a few reliable addresses, the default timeout for the check is around 10 seconds.

My finished isInternet function looked a bit like this:

```
  Future<bool> isInternet() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      // I am connected to a mobile network, make sure there is actually a net connection.
      if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
        // Mobile data detected & internet connection confirmed.
        return true;
      } else {
        // Mobile data detected but no internet connection found.
        return false;
      }
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      // I am connected to a WIFI network, make sure there is actually a net connection.
      if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
        // Wifi detected & internet connection confirmed.
        return true;
      } else {
        // Wifi detected but no internet connection found.
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // Neither mobile data or WIFI detected, not internet connection found.
      return false;
    }
  }
```

The `if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection)` part is the same for both mobile and wifi connections and should probably be moved to a separate function.  I've not done that here to leave it more readable.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just wondering, what is the advantage over just using `await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection` in the first place?

Comment: The only reason is that on IOS the connectivity package can tell pretty much instantly that there is no connection.  If I just used the  data_connection_checker package the app on  IOS would have to wait until the http request it made timed out, around 10 seconds, before returning false.   This may be acceptable in some cases though.  The connectivity package can also tell if you are using WIFI or mobile data which I don't need to know here but may be useful to know.

Comment: Thanks TDM, I've edited the answer with your modifications.

Comment: DataConnectionChecker is deprecated. Use internet_connection_checker https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker

Answer (score 24):

Using

```
dependencies:
  connectivity: ^0.4.2
```

what we got from [resouces](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-) is

```
      import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

      Future<bool> check() async {
        var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
        if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
          return true;
        } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
```

Future is little problematic for me, we have to implement it every single time like :

```
check().then((intenet) {
      if (intenet != null && intenet) {
        // Internet Present Case
      }
      // No-Internet Case
    });
```

So to solve this problem i have created a class Which accept a function with boolean isNetworkPresent parameter like this

```
methodName(bool isNetworkPresent){}
```

And the Utility Class is

> ```
> import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
>
> class NetworkCheck {
>   Future<bool> check() async {
>     var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
>     if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
>       return true;
>     } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
>       return true;
>     }
>     return false;
>   }
>
>   dynamic checkInternet(Function func) {
>     check().then((intenet) {
>       if (intenet != null && intenet) {
>         func(true);
>       }
>       else{
>     func(false);
>   }
>     });
>   }
> }
> ```

And to use connectivity-check utilty

```
  fetchPrefrence(bool isNetworkPresent) {
    if(isNetworkPresent){

    }else{

    }
  }
```

i will use this syntax

```
NetworkCheck networkCheck = new NetworkCheck();
networkCheck.checkInternet(fetchPrefrence)
```

Comment: This package is deprecated and was replaced by Connectivity Plus

Answer (score 7):

I've created a package that (I think) deals reliably with this issue.

[The package on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker)

[The package on GitHub](https://github.com/komapeb/data_connection_checker)

Discussion is very welcome. You can use the issues tracker on GitHub.

---

***I no longer think this below is a reliable method:***

---

Wanna add something to [@Oren's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242417/oren) answer: you should really add one more catch, which will catch all other exceptions (just to be safe), OR just remove the exception type altogether and use a catch, that deals with all of the exceptions:

Case 1:

```dart
try {
  await Firestore.instance
    .runTransaction((Transaction tx) {})
    .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
  hasConnection = true;
} on PlatformException catch(_) { // May be thrown on Airplane mode
  hasConnection = false;
} on TimeoutException catch(_) {
  hasConnection = false;
} catch (_) {
  hasConnection = false;
}
```

or even simpler...

Case 2:

```dart
try {
  await Firestore.instance
    .runTransaction((Transaction tx) {})
    .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
  hasConnection = true;
} catch (_) {
  hasConnection = false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I made a base class for widget state

Usage instead of `State<LoginPage>` use `BaseState<LoginPage>` 
then just use the boolean variable isOnline

```
Text(isOnline ? 'is Online' : 'is Offline')
```

First, add connectivity plugin:

```
dependencies:
  connectivity: ^0.4.3+2
```

Then add the BaseState class

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

/// a base class for any statful widget for checking internet connectivity
abstract class BaseState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State {

  void castStatefulWidget();

  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();

  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;

  /// the internet connectivity status
  bool isOnline = true;

  /// initialize connectivity checking
  /// Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> initConnectivity() async {
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    await _updateConnectionStatus().then((bool isConnected) => setState(() {
          isOnline = isConnected;
        }));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initConnectivity();
    _connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) async {
      await _updateConnectionStatus().then((bool isConnected) => setState(() {
            isOnline = isConnected;
          }));
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<bool> _updateConnectionStatus() async {
    bool isConnected;
    try {
      final List<InternetAddress> result =
          await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        isConnected = true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      isConnected = false;
      return false;
    }
    return isConnected;
  }
}
```

And you need to cast the widget in your state like this

```
@override
  void castStatefulWidget() {
    // ignore: unnecessary_statements
    widget is StudentBoardingPage;
  }
```

Comment: how can i use this class?

Comment: @DolDurma Just add it and import it then instead of State<LoginPage> use BaseState<LoginPage> then just use the boolean variable isOnline

Comment: with this code i can't get valiables from `widget`. for example: `RegisterBloc get _registerBloc => widget.registerBloc;` i get this error `error: The getter 'registerBloc' isn't defined for the class 'StatefulWidget'. (undefined_getter at lib\screens\fragmemt_register\view\register_mobile_number.dart:29)` see this implemetation: `class _FragmentRegisterMobileNumberState extends BaseState<FragmentRegisterMobileNumber> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  RegisterBloc get _registerBloc => widget.registerBloc;`

Comment: @DolDurma I am not sure what is the issue without a GitHub sample because this information is not enough

Comment: please check this repo and show me how can i use `is_online` to log in console  https://github.com/MahdiPishguy/flutter-connectivity-sample

Comment: @DolDurma just use AppBar(
        title: Text(isOnline?'Online':'Offline'),
      )

Comment: how can i resolve this error? `E/flutter ( 2969): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter ( 2969): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree`

Comment: use if(mount) in your set state

Comment: i tested that before posting comment, not any change :(

Comment: @DolDurma just use (widget as MyHomePage).title

Answer (score 7):

Well I read almost all post and  @dennmat post is most usedful to me. though it did't work for me and it is outdated too. I have update with flutter updated `connectivity` package(i.e `connectivity_plus`) and `data_connection_checker`(to check whether there is actual internet connection for mobile and wifi).
*After this post you will be able to listen for internet connection continuosly.*

**1. Add dependencies**
a) [connectivity_plus: ^1.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity)
b) [data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker)

**2. Custom class that handle all the connection.**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:data_connection_checker/data_connection_checker.dart'; 

class ConnectionUtil {
  //This creates the single instance by calling the `_internal` constructor specified below
  static final ConnectionUtil _singleton = new ConnectionUtil._internal();
  ConnectionUtil._internal();
  //This is what's used to retrieve the instance through the app
  static ConnectionUtil getInstance() => _singleton;
  //This tracks the current connection status
  bool hasConnection = false;
  //This is how we'll allow subscribing to connection changes
  StreamController connectionChangeController = StreamController();
  //flutter_connectivity
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  void initialize() {
    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_connectionChange);
  }
  //flutter_connectivity's listener
  void _connectionChange(ConnectivityResult result) {
    hasInternetInternetConnection();
  }
  Stream get connectionChange => connectionChangeController.stream;
  Future<bool> hasInternetInternetConnection() async {
    bool previousConnection = hasConnection;
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    //Check if device is just connect with mobile network or wifi
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
        connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      //Check there is actual internet connection with a mobile network or wifi
      if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
        // Network data detected & internet connection confirmed.
        hasConnection = true;
      } else {
        // Network data detected but no internet connection found.
        hasConnection = false;
      }
    }
    // device has no mobile network and wifi connection at all
    else {
      hasConnection = false;
    }
    // The connection status changed send out an update to all listeners
    if (previousConnection != hasConnection) {
      connectionChangeController.add(hasConnection);
    }
    return hasConnection;
  }
}
```

3. Check for connection in anywhere and listen for change.

```
@override
  initState() {
    print('called');
    //Create instance
    ConnectionUtil connectionStatus = ConnectionUtil.getInstance();
    //Initialize
    connectionStatus.initialize();
    //Listen for connection change
    _connectionChangeStream = connectionStatus.connectionChange.listen((event) {
      print(event);
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

Now check the log while toggle flight mode. you should get log with true and false value.

***Note: this will not work in flutter web, if you wish to make it work than use `dio` or `http` plugin instead of `data_connection_checker`.***

Example Project can be found [here](https://github.com/CodingWithTashi/Flutter-Network-Checker). Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But can you tell me if i have to put this piece of code in every ```initState``` or not? And If so, how can I do some work around that make the check somelike global check over all the application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously this is not the best approach, You could use some state management tool like provider or bloc to listen for stream and emit the change.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity is discontinued

Comment: correct which is why I have already added connectivity_plus

Comment: `data_connection_checker` is discontinued. Use `internet_connection_checker`.

Answer (score 5):

I had an issue with the proposed solutions, using `lookup` does not always return the expected value.

This is due to DNS caching, the value of the call is cached and intead of doing a proper call on the next try it gives back the cached value. Of course this is an issue here as it means if you lose connectivity and call `lookup` it could still return the cached value as if you had internet, and conversely, if you reconnect your internet after `lookup` returned null it will still return null for the duration of the cache, which can be a few minutes, even if you do have internet now.

TL;DR: `lookup` returning something does not necessarily mean you have internet, and it not returning anything does not necessarily mean you don't have internet. It is not reliable.

I implemented the following solution by taking inspiration from the `data_connection_checker` plugin:

```
 /// If any of the pings returns true then you have internet (for sure). If none do, you probably don't.
  Future<bool> _checkInternetAccess() {
    /// We use a mix of IPV4 and IPV6 here in case some networks only accept one of the types.
    /// Only tested with an IPV4 only network so far (I don't have access to an IPV6 network).
    final List<InternetAddress> dnss = [
      InternetAddress('8.8.8.8', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4), // Google
      InternetAddress('2001:4860:4860::8888', type: InternetAddressType.IPv6), // Google
      InternetAddress('1.1.1.1', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4), // CloudFlare
      InternetAddress('2606:4700:4700::1111', type: InternetAddressType.IPv6), // CloudFlare
      InternetAddress('208.67.222.222', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4), // OpenDNS
      InternetAddress('2620:0:ccc::2', type: InternetAddressType.IPv6), // OpenDNS
      InternetAddress('180.76.76.76', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4), // Baidu
      InternetAddress('2400:da00::6666', type: InternetAddressType.IPv6), // Baidu
    ];

    final Completer<bool> completer = Completer<bool>();

    int callsReturned = 0;
    void onCallReturned(bool isAlive) {
      if (completer.isCompleted) return;

      if (isAlive) {
        completer.complete(true);
      } else {
        callsReturned++;
        if (callsReturned >= dnss.length) {
          completer.complete(false);
        }
      }
    }

    dnss.forEach((dns) => _pingDns(dns).then(onCallReturned));

    return completer.future;
  }

  Future<bool> _pingDns(InternetAddress dnsAddress) async {
    const int dnsPort = 53;
    const Duration timeout = Duration(seconds: 3);

    Socket socket;
    try {
      socket = await Socket.connect(dnsAddress, dnsPort, timeout: timeout);
      socket?.destroy();
      return true;
    } on SocketException {
      socket?.destroy();
    }
    return false;
  }
```

The call to `_checkInternetAccess` takes at most a duration of `timeout` to complete (3 seconds here), and if we can reach any of the DNS it will complete as soon as the first one is reached, without waiting for the others (as reaching one is enough to know you have internet). All the calls to `_pingDns` are done in parallel.

It seems to work well on an IPV4 network, and when I can't test it on an IPV6 network (I don't have access to one) I think it should still work. It also works on release mode builds, but I yet have to submit my app to Apple to see if they find any issue with this solution.

It should also work in most countries (including China), if it does not work in one you can add a DNS to the list that is accessible from your target country.

Comment: I think this will suffice more than enough ```dart
Future<bool> isConnectedToInternet() async {
  try {
    (await Socket.connect(
      InternetAddress('8.8.8.8', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4),
      53,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    ))
        .destroy();
  } on SocketException {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Following @dennmatt 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53855326), I noticed that `InternetAddress.lookup` may return successful results even if the internet connection is off - I tested it by connecting from my simulator to my home WiFi, and then disconnecting my router's cable. I think the reason is that the router caches the domain-lookup results so it does not have to query the DNS servers on each lookup request.

Anyways, if you use Firestore like me, you can replace the try-SocketException-catch block with an empty transaction and catch TimeoutExceptions:

```
try {
  await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) {}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
  hasConnection = true;
} on PlatformException catch(_) { // May be thrown on Airplane mode
  hasConnection = false;
} on TimeoutException catch(_) {
  hasConnection = false;
}
```

Also, please notice that `previousConnection` is set before the async intenet-check, so theoretically if `checkConnection()` is called multiple times in a short time, there could be multiple `hasConnection=true` in a row or multiple `hasConnection=false` in a row.
I'm not sure if @dennmatt did it on purpose or not, but in our use-case there were no side effects (`setState` was only called twice with the same value).

Answer (score 3):

The connectivity: package does not guarantee the actual internet connection
(could be just wifi connection without internet access).

Quote from the documentation:

> Note that on Android, this does not guarantee connection to Internet. For instance, the app might have wifi access but it might be a VPN or a hotel WiFi with no access.

If you really need to check the connection to the www Internet the better choice would be

[data_connection_checker package](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker#-readme-tab-)

Comment: AGREED. That is why combining the __**Connectivity**__ and __**Data Connection Checker**__ packages (as explained here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/62063600/3002719) is a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

### use  [connectivity_widget: ^0.1.7](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_widget/install)

**add dependencies:**

```
dependencies:
     connectivity_widget: ^0.1.7
```

**add code:**

```
           ConnectivityWidget(
            builder: (context, isOnline) => Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "${isOnline ? 'Connected' : 'Offline'}",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: isOnline ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: this packge dose not support null safety now

Answer (score 2):

### Here Is My Solution It Checks Internet Connectivity as well as Data Connection I hope You Like it.

First of all add dependencies in your pubsec.yaml

```
dependencies:        
    data_connection_checker:
```

And Here Is The main.dart Of My Solution

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:data_connection_checker/data_connection_checker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Data Connection Checker",
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  StreamSubscription<DataConnectionStatus> listener;

  var Internetstatus = "Unknown";

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
//    _updateConnectionStatus();
      CheckInternet();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    listener.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  CheckInternet() async {
    // Simple check to see if we have internet
    print("The statement 'this machine is connected to the Internet' is: ");
    print(await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection);
    // returns a bool

    // We can also get an enum instead of a bool
    print("Current status: ${await DataConnectionChecker().connectionStatus}");
    // prints either DataConnectionStatus.connected
    // or DataConnectionStatus.disconnected

    // This returns the last results from the last call
    // to either hasConnection or connectionStatus
    print("Last results: ${DataConnectionChecker().lastTryResults}");

    // actively listen for status updates
    listener = DataConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen((status) {
      switch (status) {
        case DataConnectionStatus.connected:
          Internetstatus="Connectd TO THe Internet";
          print('Data connection is available.');
          setState(() {

          });
          break;
        case DataConnectionStatus.disconnected:
          Internetstatus="No Data Connection";
          print('You are disconnected from the internet.');
          setState(() {

          });
          break;
      }
    });

    // close listener after 30 seconds, so the program doesn't run forever
//    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30));
//    await listener.cancel();
    return await await DataConnectionChecker().connectionStatus;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Data Connection Checker"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("$Internetstatus"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ultimately (**though reluctantly**) settled on the solution given by @abernee in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61518327/3002719) to this question. I always try and use as few external packages in my projects as possible - as I know external packages are the only [ potential ] points of failure in the software I create. So to link to **TWO** external packages just for a simple implementation like this was **not easy for me**.

Nevertheless, I took abernee's code and modified it to make it leaner and more sensible. By sensible I mean he consumes the power of the [Connectivity package](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) in his function but then wastes it internally by not returning the most valuable outputs from this package ( i.e. the network identification ). So here is the modified version of abernee's solution:

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:data_connection_checker/data_connection_checker.dart';


// 'McGyver' - the ultimate cool guy (the best helper class any app can ask for).
class McGyver {

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> checkInternetAccess() async {
    //* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *//
    //*   INFO: ONLY TWO return TYPES for Map 'dynamic' value => <bool> and <ConnectivityResult>   *//
    //* ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// *//
    Map<String, dynamic> mapCon;
    final String isConn = 'isConnected', netType = 'networkType';
    ConnectivityResult conRes = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    switch (conRes) {
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:   //* WiFi Network: true !!
        if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {   //* Internet Access: true !!
          mapCon = Map.unmodifiable({isConn: true, netType: ConnectivityResult.wifi});
        } else {
          mapCon = Map.unmodifiable({isConn: false, netType: ConnectivityResult.wifi});
        }
        break;
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:   //* Mobile Network: true !!
        if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {   //* Internet Access: true !!
          mapCon = Map.unmodifiable({isConn: true, netType: ConnectivityResult.mobile});
        } else {
          mapCon = Map.unmodifiable({isConn: false, netType: ConnectivityResult.mobile});
        }
        break;
      case ConnectivityResult.none:   //* No Network: true !!
        mapCon = Map.unmodifiable({isConn: false, netType: ConnectivityResult.none});
        break;
    }
    return mapCon;
  }

}
```

---

Then you'd use this static function via a simple call from anywhere in your code as follows:

```
bool isConn; ConnectivityResult netType;
McGyver.checkInternetAccess().then(
  (mapCIA) {  //* 'mapCIA' == amalgamation for 'map' from 'CheckInternetAccess' function result.
    debugPrint("'mapCIA' Keys: ${mapCIA.keys}");
    isConn = mapCIA['isConnected'];
    netType = mapCIA['networkType'];
  }
);
debugPrint("Internet Access: $isConn   |   Network Type: $netType");
```

---

It's a pity that you have to link to **TWO EXTERNAL PACKAGES** to get this very **basic functionality** in your Flutter project - but I guess for now this is the best we have. I actually prefer the [Data Connection Checker](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker) package over the [Connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package - but (at the time of posting this) the former was missing that very important **network identification feature** that I require from the Connectivity package. This is the reason I defaulted onto this approach [ temporarily ].

Answer (score 2):

I have written a package to check the active internet connection and display a widget accordingly.

[flutter_no_internet_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_no_internet_widget)

Example:

```
InternetWidget(
 online: Text('Online'),
 offline: Text('Offline),
);
```

As per the network state, the appropriate widgets will be displayed. If you have an active internet connection an online widget will be displayed.

All the heavyweight is done by the package and all you have to do is provide online and offline widgets. Optionally you can provide a loading widget and lookup URL.

Discussion, PRs or suggestions are welcome.

[image: internet-widget-video]

Comment: well done ! i fork it  ;)

Comment: Thanks, @EsmaeilAhmadipour, I'm also working on displaying the Snackbar, bottom sheet and popup too. You can see that in the master branch. I haven't released it yet as I'm still testing.

Answer (score 2):

To check whether you have internet access or not, even if you are connected to wifi, use the below function.

```
Future<bool> checkInternetStatus() async {
    try {
      final url = Uri.https('google.com');
     var response = await http.head(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

also add http: ^0.13.5 dependency
then import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Comment: This will take a long time before returning due to connection timeout. Not a fast solution

Comment: You can fast-pace it by just loading head. `await http.head(url);` This will just download header.

Answer (score 2):

We are in 2024, and I wanted to contribute to try to make life easier for new people who land on this old question.
Most of the answers given above are probably obsolete nowadays due to changing technologies.

To reliably check that you actually have access to the internet (via wifi or mobile data), simply use the **internet_connection_checker_plus** widget.

**1 -** add this permissions to your *AndroidManifest.xml* file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

**2 -** execute the flutter pub add internet_connection_checker_plus command in your terminal, this will add the latest version of the widget available, currently it is:
`internet_connection_checker_plus: ^2.1.0`

**3 -** add **import** `package:internet_connection_checker_plus/internet_connection_checker_plus.dart`; on your project's *.dart* file

Now all you have to do is use the InternetConnection class anywhere in your project to verify that the internet is available before each action that requires an internet connection:

```
if(await InternetConnection().hasInternetAccess){
    //You have access to the internet, do what you want
}else{
    //You don't have access to the internet, do what you want
}
```

> For example

```
  onPressed: () async {

    if(await InternetConnection().hasInternetAccess){

        print("You are online");

     }else{

         print("You are offline");

     }

   },
```

To listen to the change in state of the internet connection you can use

```
final listener = InternetConnection().onStatusChange.listen((InternetStatus status) {
   switch (status) {
     case InternetStatus.connected:
       // The internet is now connected
       break;
     case InternetStatus.disconnected:
       // The internet is now disconnected
       break;
   }
});
```

For more details please refer to the widget page https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker_plus

Answer (score 1):

late answer, but use this package to to check.
Package Name: data_connection_checker

in you pubspec.yuml file:

```
dependencies:
    data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
```

create a file called connection.dart or any name you want.
import the package:

```
import 'package:data_connection_checker/data_connection_checker.dart';
```

check if there is internet connection or not:

```
print(await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection);
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the data_connection_checker package to check the internet access even if the connection available by wifi or mobile, it works well:
here is the code to check the connection:

```
bool result = await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
if(result == true) {
   print('YAY! Free cute dog pics!');
} else {
   print('No internet :( Reason:');
   print(DataConnectionChecker().lastTryResults);
}
```

head over the package if you want more information.
[Data Connection Checker Package](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker)

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

class InternetConnect extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  InternetConnectState createState() => InternetConnectState();
}

class InternetConnectState extends State<InternetConnect> {
  ConnectivityResult previous;
  bool dialogshown = false;
  StreamSubscription connectivitySubscription;

  Future<bool> checkinternet() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return Future.value(true);
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  }

  void checkInternetConnect(BuildContext context) {
    connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult connresult) {
      if (connresult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        dialogshown = true;
        showDialog(
            context: context, barrierDismissible: false, child: alertDialog());
      } else if (previous == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        checkinternet().then((result) {
          if (result == true) {
            if (dialogshown == true) {
              dialogshown = false;
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          }
        });
      }

      previous = connresult;
    });
  }

  AlertDialog alertDialog() {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('ERROR'),
      content: Text("No Internet Detected."),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          // method to exit application programitacally

          onPressed: () {
            AppSettings.openWIFISettings();
          },
          child: Text("Settings"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

    and you can use this method in init of any class

@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  InternetConnectState().checkInternetConnect(context);
  super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68436867/10761151

If you used dart null safety you will get an error,
so you can **update** the dependencies **data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4** to **internet_connection_checker: ^0.0.1+2**

and you can use this code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';

class ConnectionUtil {
  static final ConnectionUtil _singleton = new ConnectionUtil._internal();
  ConnectionUtil._internal();

  static ConnectionUtil getInstance() => _singleton;

  bool hasConnection = false;

  StreamController connectionChangeController = StreamController();

  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  void initialize() {
    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_connectionChange);
  }

  void _connectionChange(ConnectivityResult result) {
    _hasInternetInternetConnection();
  }

  Stream get connectionChange => connectionChangeController.stream;
  Future<bool> _hasInternetInternetConnection() async {
    bool previousConnection = hasConnection;
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      // this is the different
      if (await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
        hasConnection = true;
      } else {
        hasConnection = false;
      }
    } else {
      hasConnection = false;
    }

    if (previousConnection != hasConnection) {
      connectionChangeController.add(hasConnection);
    }
    return hasConnection;
  }
}
```

and on the stateful widget you can implement this code

```
  bool hasInterNetConnection = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    ConnectionUtil connectionStatus = ConnectionUtil.getInstance();
    connectionStatus.initialize();
    connectionStatus.connectionChange.listen(connectionChanged);

    super.initState();
  }

  void connectionChanged(dynamic hasConnection) {
    setState(() {
      hasInterNetConnection = hasConnection;
    });
  }
```

Comment: connectionChanged get called multiple times(=number of time  I called initSate, i.e, every time the stateful widget is invoked). This happens even after I cancel the 'stream' in the 'dispose' method. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to simplify the code using [Connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity#-readme-tab-) Package in Flutter.

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  // I am connected to a wifi network.
} else {
  // I am not connected to the internet
}
```

Comment: The issue with this on Android though is that just because you are connected via wifi or mobile, it doesen't mean you are connected to the internet.

Comment: @Megadec sadly yes thats the only problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I having some problem with the accepted answer, but it seems it solve answer for others. I would like a solution that can get a response from the url it uses, so I thought http would be great for that functionality, and for that I found this answer really helpful. [How do I check Internet Connectivity using HTTP requests(Flutter/Dart)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61036643/how-do-i-check-internet-connectivity-using-http-requestsflutter-dart)

Answer (score 0):

For me I just create a single data in Firebase and use future builder to await for the data. Here, like this, you can check if the connection is too slow so the data will be loading:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _getImage(context),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
          return Text('Press button to start.');
        case ConnectionState.active:
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Container(
              height:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.25,
              width:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.25,
              child: Loading());
        case ConnectionState.done:
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return snapshot.data;
          } else {
            return FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            ProfilePage()));
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add_a_photo,
                size: 50,
              ),
            );
          }
        // You can reach your snapshot.data['url'] in here
      }
      return null;
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this package
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_network_connectivity

Underhood it makes use of NetworkCapabilities on Android and NetworkMonitor on iOS and listens to connectivity changes and pings to check internet availability, you can also configure to lookup internet availability in a periodic interval.

Add to your pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_network_connectivity: ^0.0.6
```

Create an Object

```
FlutterNetworkConnectivity flutterNetworkConnectivity =
    FlutterNetworkConnectivity(
      isContinousLookUp: true,  // optional, false if you cont want continous lookup
      lookUpDuration: const Duration(seconds: 5),  // optional, to override default lookup duration
      lookUpUrl: 'example.com',  // optional, to override default lookup url
);
```

and you can use its methods to check for network connectivity continuously or a call to check the current status

```
_flutterNetworkConnectivity.getInternetAvailabilityStream().listen((isInternetAvailable) {
  // do something
});
```

and register listener

```
await _flutterNetworkConnectivity.registerAvailabilityListener();
```

to check status on call

```
bool _isNetworkConnectedOnCall = await _flutterNetworkConnectivity.isInternetConnectionAvailable();
```

Comment: I think it is worth to mention that `flutter_network_connectivity` cannot be used for flutter web development. The mentioned library uses `dart:io` which can't be used in web built flutter applications. For further info please read the following github issue: https://github.com/thisisamir98/connection_status_bar/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

final ConnectivityResult result =
await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();

```
if (result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  print('Connected to a Wi-Fi network');
} else if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  print('Connected to a mobile network');
} else {
  print('Not connected to any network');
}
```

Comment: Use connectivity_plus package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [observe_internet_connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/observe_internet_connectivity) package.

### Available Features

1. **Check to know if a device has internet connection**

```dart
  final hasInternet = await InternetConnectivity().hasInternetConnection;
  if (hasInternet) {
    //You are connected to the internet
  } else {
    //"No internet connection
  }
```

2. **Listen to internet connection changes via stream**

```dart
  final subscription =
      InternetConnectivity().observeInternetConnection.listen((bool hasInternetAccess) {
        if(!hasInternetAccess){
          showToast('No Internet Connection');
        }
      });

   await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10 ));
   subscription.cancel();
```

3. **Use `InternetConnectivityListener` to listen to internet connectivity changes inside a flutter widget**

```dart
    return InternetConnectivityListener(
      connectivityListener: (BuildContext context, bool hasInternetAccess) {
        if (hasInternetAccess) {
          context.showBanner('You are back Online!', color: Colors.green);
        } else {
          context.showBanner('No internet connection', color: Colors.red);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
```

4. **Use `InternetConnectivityBuilder` to build internet connection aware widgets**

```dart
    return InternetConnectivityBuilder(
      connectivityBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool hasInternetAccess, Widget? child) { 
        if(hasInternetAccess) {
          return OnlineWidget();
        } else {
          return OfflineWidget();
        }
      },
      child: ChildWidget(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

As this an old question a lot of things has be changed since last 5 years and `connectivity_plus` is no more working (at least for me) as I tried it today.

Luckily I found https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker which works like a charm, for checking internet connectivity.

As the author says the **Purpose** of the package:

> The reason this package exists is that `connectivity_plus` package
> cannot reliably determine if a data connection is actually available.
> More info on its page here: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

So recommend using `internet_connection_checker` and below code should work:

```
bool result = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
if(result == true) {
  print('YAY! Free cute dog pics!');
} else {
  print('No internet :( Reason:');
  // print(InternetConnectionChecker().lastTryResults);
}
```

Best thing is its all dart, which is what flutter is based on.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the connectivity package is that it only triggers, if the interface goes completely down. As I am not really interested how the user is connected, but rather IF he is connected, I came up with this solution that can be wrapped around any other widget that requires internet access.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConnectivityWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConnectivityWidget({super.key, required this.child});
  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<ConnectivityWidget> createState() => _ConnectivityWidgetState();
}

class _ConnectivityWidgetState extends State<ConnectivityWidget> {
  final myConnectivity = MyConnectivity.instance;
  bool? isOnline;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myConnectivity.continueslyCheckInternetConnection().listen((result) {
      setState(() => isOnline = result);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isOnline == null) {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text('Checking internet connection...')),
      );
    }
    if (isOnline == false) {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text('No Internet connection.', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red))),
      );
    }
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    debugPrint('NEVER SHOULD HAPPEN: Disposing MainApp...');
    myConnectivity.disposeStream();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class MyConnectivity {
  MyConnectivity._();

  static final _instance = MyConnectivity._();
  static MyConnectivity get instance => _instance;
  final _controller = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

  Stream<bool> continueslyCheckInternetConnection() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) async {
      bool isOnline = false;
      try {
        final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('www.google.com');
        isOnline = result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
      } on SocketException catch (_) {
        isOnline = false;
      }
      final timestamp = DateTime.timestamp().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
      debugPrint('$timestamp - Internet:$isOnline');
      _controller.add(isOnline);
    });
    return _controller.stream;
  }

  void disposeStream() => _controller.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today is 2023, Here is the solution I have

```
try {
    final dio = Dio();
    final response = await dio.get('https://www.google.com');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      internetAccessible = "Ready";
    } else {
      internetAccessible = "Not Ready";
    }
  } catch (_) {
    internetAccessible = "Not Ready";
  }
```

This seems to work on my android pad with wlan turn off, and connect to  wifi that has no internet.

Comment: You should add `on DioException` before `catch()` block, to let Dio determine the errors, [check here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#handling-errors)

Answer (score 0):

In order to check internet connection, you can ping google.com or any address you want with [dart_ping](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ping) package.
Before using this package, I used InternetAddress lookup method. But probably it can return result from dns cache. So, using that is not consistent.

```
final result = await Ping('google.com', count: 1).stream.first;
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution  :

```
Future<bool> checkInternet() async {
      try {
        final response = await http.head(Uri.parse('https://www.google.com'));
        return response.statusCode == 200;
      } catch (_) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplest straight forward way

```dart
  try {
    final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      print('connected');
    }
  } on SocketException catch (_) {
    print('not connected');
  }
```

#### The best, robust and solid way

1. create an abstract class

```dart
abstract class InternetCheck {
    Future<bool> get connected;
}
```

2. create an implementation for that class, override the getter **connected** and add the implementation want, either using a package like [ConnectivtyPlus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) or [data_connection_checker_tv](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker_tv) which i prefer.

```dart
class InternetCheckImpl1 implements InternetCheck {
  @override
  Future<bool> get connected async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      return result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty;
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  }
}

class InternetCheckImpl2 implements InternetCheck {
  InternetCheckImpl2(this.connectionChecker);

  final DataConnectionChecker connectionChecker;

  @override
  Future<bool> get connected => connectionChecker.hasConnection;
}
```

You may ask why this complexity since we can do it the easy way ? ok here is why

1. You can inject it in your dependency injection framework to easily access it wherever you need, and just await the getter before doing any network-related operation
2. You centralised your internet check, and you can easily swap implementation whenever you need(in your DI just specify any of the 2 implementation you want for InternetCheck), update it in 1 place and will apply anywhere you used it
3. You can create custom implementation for testing, if you are fan of testing
4. Its a more robust and awesome way!

```dart
/// implementations for testing

class InternetMockImplActive implements InternetCheck {
  @override
  Future<bool> get connected async => true;
}

class InternetMockImplInactive implements InternetCheck {
  @override
  Future<bool> get connected async => false;
}


/// injecting it in DI

injection.registerLazySingleton<InternetCheck>(() => 
InternetCheckImpl1(),
// InternetCheckImpl2(),
// InternetMockImplActive(),
// InternetMockImplInactive(),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The connectivity plugin states in its docs that it only provides information if there is a network connection, but not if the network is connected to the Internet. Use the below code and don't forget to use ".timeout()" because you can stuck forever using "await".

```
import 'dart:io';

Future<bool> isConnected() async {
  try {
    List<InternetAddress> result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com')
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

    //
    if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
      return true;
    }
    //
    else {
      return false;
    }
  } on SocketException catch (_) {
    return false;
  }
}
```