# Why is my addValueEventListener not working as it should?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to implement a profile page for an Android app using android studio and java. I have an activity that uploads the users profile information to firebase and now I'm trying to make my profile activity fetch the users information from firebase and display it on the screen. In order to do this, I made a database reference called contactInfo which references to where the given users profile information is. However, When I try to ran this snippet through the debugger, none of the code inside of the addValueEvent handers was ever reached and I'm not sure why. If anyone has any ideas or fixes for this issue I would really appreciate it.

```
        contactInfo.child("email").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            contactEmail = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            email.setText(contactEmail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Failed to get email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    contactInfo.child("address").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            contactAddress = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Got Addy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            address.setText(contactAddress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Failed to get addy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    contactInfo.child("phoneNumber").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            contactPhone = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            phoneNumber.setText(contactPhone);
        }
```

Comment: Instead of stepping through the code, set breakpoints on the first line inside `onDataChange` and `onCancelled`. If you now run the code in the debugger again, does it reach either of those breakpoints?

Comment: I set a break point on the first line of one of the oneDataChange. After running through the debugger, it looks like neither of these statements are reached. Which is quite odd. I'm not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: Did you also put a breakpoint on `onCancelled`? If you have a connection to the Firebase servers, one or the other will be called. If neither gets called, it typically means you have no connection.

Comment: I set a break point for the line under OnCancelled but when I run through the debugger, the app never reaches this line. Essentially, I click on a button that open a new activity and this code is under the onCreate portion of this activity. This is weird because I don't think my lack of a connection is the issue since I am able to connect to FireBase in other parts of my application.

Comment: You might try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279144/how-to-verify-if-user-has-network-access-and-show-a-pop-up-alert-when-there-isn?noredirect=1&lq=1), to see if you're really connected or not.