# Created a login screen using Firebase but it does not seem to work as expected

Tags: java, xml, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I created a firebased DB and have a login screen but my login screen doesn't seem to do anything I can see in Logcat that nothing is happening when I put details in and click the Login button any help in what I am doing wrong here. code below for MainActivity and xml file.

```
package com.example.firebaseintro;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private EditText email;
    private EditText password;
    private Button login;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailED);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordED);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        databaseReference = database.getReference("message");

        databaseReference.setValue("another World");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user !=null) {
                    //User is Signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "User Signed In");
                }else {
                    //User is Signed Out
                    Log.d(TAG, "User Signed Out");
                }
            }
        };

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String emailString = email.getText().toString();
                String pwd = password.getText().toString();

                if (emailString.equals("") && !pwd.equals("")){
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailString, pwd)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed Sign In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .show();
                                    }else {

                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed In!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .show();
                                        databaseReference.setValue("Hey I am Working");
                                    }

                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mAuthListner !=null){
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
        }
    }
}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailED"
        android:layout_width="327dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.064"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordED"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailED"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="284dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordED" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
12-13 13:25:05.453 11690-11690/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-13 13:25:05.618 11690-11690/com.example.firebaseintro W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.firebaseintro-1/lib/x86
12-13 13:25:05.738 11690-11690/com.example.firebaseintro I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
12-13 13:25:05.767 11690-11690/com.example.firebaseintro I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
12-13 13:25:06.088 11690-11690/com.example.firebaseintro W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
12-13 13:25:06.153 11690-11716/com.example.firebaseintro I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to fallback implementation
12-13 13:25:06.603 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-13 13:25:06.648 11690-11690/com.example.firebaseintro D/MainActivity: User Signed Out
12-13 13:25:06.719 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-13 13:25:06.719 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-13 13:25:06.744 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae424780: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
12-13 13:25:06.750 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae424780: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae43e4f0)
12-13 13:25:06.754 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
12-13 13:25:06.754 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
12-13 13:25:06.755 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
12-13 13:25:07.221 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae424780: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae43e4f0)
12-13 13:25:07.844 11690-11690/com.example.firebaseintro I/Choreographer: Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-13 13:25:08.185 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae424780: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae43e4f0)
12-13 13:25:08.228 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae424780: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae43e4f0)
12-13 13:25:08.247 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae424780: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae43e4f0)
12-13 13:25:08.338 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro V/RenderScript: 0xa12c9000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
12-13 13:25:08.725 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae424780: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae43e4f0)
12-13 13:25:10.169 11690-11722/com.example.firebaseintro E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaaa8b2c0
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response the code runs fine but when i run it and i get my login screen for email and password thats the section that does nothing no matter what i put there i dont get my Toast showing on screen

Comment: Is any of `onDataChange` or `onCancelled` even triggered?

Comment: doesnt look like they are getting triggered

Comment: added logcat aswell

Comment: Then most likely you don't have an internet connection on user's device, right?

Comment: im not sure Alex how do i check that im working with virtual device

Comment: You can check like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52279317/5246885).

Comment: Great news thanks for all the help i go this work!!! my OnDataChange was the problem and wasnt looking at the correct place(datasnapshot changed to snapshot) hope this helps anyone else in the future.