# How to retrieve data from merge tasks in firestore query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

> please can someone tell me how to retrieve all three tasks? Actually, I'm able to retrieve only two tasks.

CollectionReference players = db.collection("gamers");

```
    Task task1 = players.whereEqualTo("player_id_one", myId)
            .get();

    Task task2 = players.whereEqualTo("player_id_two", myId)
            .get();
Task task3 = players.whereEqualTo("player_id_three",myId).get();

    Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> allTasks = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(task1, task2,task3);
    allTasks.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<QuerySnapshot>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshots) {
            for (QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots : querySnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Modelgame players = documentSnapshot.toObject(Modelgame.class);
                    result.add(modelplayer);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can give a try by adding `task4` and then you may get 3 instead of 4

Comment: Oh I see.. but i have no idea how I'm supposed to arrange the for loop so that it display the results. If you have any ideas please your welcome

Comment: Can you tell me what output or error you are getting in your case. and what output or error after adding `task4`.

Comment: Actually no error occurred.  My code retrieve only two tasks but when i add the third and the fourth task. Nothing display in my recyclerView .

Comment: thank you I saw the problem firestore asked me to add an index query in my console ‍♂️..  It finally works

Answer (score 1):

When you're using [Tasks#whenAllSuccess(Task...<?> tasks)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) method it:

> Returns a Task with a list of Task results that completes successfully when all of the specified Tasks complete successfully.

This means that the List you're getting is **not** a `List<QuerySnapshot>` but a `List<Object>`:

```
allTasks.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> querySnapshots) {
        //Loop through the list only once
        for (Object object : querySnapshots) {
            Modelgame players = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(Modelgame.class);
            result.add(modelplayer);
            Log.d("TAG", players.getName());
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Added when the for loop ends.
    }
});
```

So once all the tasks are successful you only need to loop through the results once and cast the object to a `DocumentSnapshot` object and call `toObject()`.

Comment: i just tried it . My recyclerView display nothing it remains blank

Comment: Does this `Log.d("TAG", players.getName());` pint something in the logcat? If you don't have a getter for the name, then use another one. Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Have you also tried to use a hard-coded value for `myId`?

Comment: I tried the code again but this time an error occurred. Java.lang.Class.CastException: com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot

Comment: thank you I saw the problem firestore asked me to add an index query in my console ‍♂️..  It finally works

Comment: actually yes. Check internet connection.. check internet bandwidth

Comment: actually yes. is there a firestore or firebase code to check the internet connection?

Comment: For that, I recommend you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52279144/how-to-verify-if-user-has-network-access-and-show-a-pop-up-alert-when-there-isn). So like the answer states, you can use `.isFromCache()`, right?

Comment: Can I help you with other information, other than that?