# how to check first time loading internet available on Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Above GitHub code is working well. Problem is before the app starts I turn off internet connection(mobile or wifi). but the output is showing Connected. After turn on the internet, showing Connected also and again turn off the internet showing Not-Connected. The first time is not the correct result after working well. How to fix this issue?

**This how explains this code**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53855326/8822337

**I used this GitHub code**
https://github.com/dennmat/flutter-connectiontest-example

Comment: can you be more clear about ur problem ??

Comment: I edited my code.can you download GitHub repo and try it?