# Check internet connection with Connectivity

Tags: flutter

I want to check the internet connection through out my application in following manner:

[image]

Comment: im not shure but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the exactly what you are looking for https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_offline