# How to load image when if only i have internet connection in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter

I want to load an image if only I have internet connection, if it doesn't have internet I don't want to load image?

Currently, when I open my app with no internet connection the image once fails to load an image and it won't again load image until I restart my app?

Is there any way if I can load the image back again when I reconnect to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56959146/6618622), you can listen to internet connectivity change and try something like

```
bool hasConnection;
```

...

```
if (hasConnection) {
  // reload image here
} else {
  // maybe load an image from asset?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by using ValueKey in which current DateTime as a value

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                            key: ValueKey(DateTime.now()),
                            placeholder: "lib/asset/images/no_image(1).jpg",
                            image: _movies[index].data['image'],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
```