# How do you check internet ACCESS continously in flutter.dart, not connection

Tags: firebase, flutter, connection, stream-builder

how do you continously check internet access? I was able to show if wifi is connectected or mobile data. However, not all connection would have internet access.

```
 import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  // I am connected to a wifi network.
}
```

This is currently the code im using.
I was hoping how someone could check continously of internet access?

Comment: I might be able to help. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app/68436867#68436867

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Here is the way you can build Network Aware applications**

***High level overview***

1. Create a service that listen to Connectivity change events, for
   example wifi, mobile and none (offline). This service will emit
   NewtorkStatus (our custom class) into a stream every time the
   Connectivity changes.
2. Create consumer for the above NetworkStatus stream that will be
   notified everytime the NetworkStatus changes.
3. Based on the network status rebuild the HomeScreen to show either
   online or offline contents.

Sounds tricky but its actually easy to implement, we will be using `connectivity` & `provider` package to our rescue.

Firstly configure our project to use above dependencies, edit `pubspec.yaml` to include the dependencies -

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  provider: ^6.0.1
```

Run `$ pub get` you synchronise all the dependencies.

Now we will create our own `NewtorkStatusService` this service will use `NetworkStatus` enumeration with two states `Online` & `Offline` to notify the Connectivity state.

**network_status_service.dart**

```
enum NetworkStatus { 
  Online, 
  Offline 
}
```

Now our NetworkStatusService will use the Connectivity package to get status of current connection status (wifi, mobile, none) and based on that it will emit a new NetworkStatus to stream. Our final NetworkStatusService would look something like this -

**network_status_service.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

enum NetworkStatus { Online, Offline }

class NetworkStatusService {
  StreamController<NetworkStatus> networkStatusController =
      StreamController<NetworkStatus>();

  NetworkStatusService() {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((status){
      networkStatusController.add(_getNetworkStatus(status));
    });
  }

  NetworkStatus _getNetworkStatus(ConnectivityResult status) {
    return status == ConnectivityResult.mobile || status == ConnectivityResult.wifi ? NetworkStatus.Online : NetworkStatus.Offline;
  }
}
```

Now we will create our won custom widget that will return either an `onlineChild` or `offlineChild` based on **NetworkStatus** value. Here we will use `provider` package to get **NetworkStatus**. I would look something like this -

**network_aware_widget.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_network_aware_app/services/network_status_service.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class NetworkAwareWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget onlineChild;
  final Widget offlineChild;

  const NetworkAwareWidget({Key? key, required this.onlineChild, required this.offlineChild})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = Provider.of<NetworkStatus>(context);
    if (networkStatus == NetworkStatus.Online) {
      return onlineChild;
    } else {
      _showToastMessage("Offline");
      return offlineChild;
    }
  }

  void _showToastMessage(String message){
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: message,
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1
    );
  }
}
```

Here I am also using the `FlutterToast` to show toast message (just to add some interactivity to app)

Now's the fun part we will bring all the pieces together to make our app respond to NetworkStatus value. We will use out custom made widget inside a `StreamProvider` widget. The `StreamProvider` will subscribe on the **NewtorkStatusService** networkStatusController stream and trigger a build on child components every time the NetworkStatus changes to `Online` or `Offline`. Here's how it will look -

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_network_aware_app/services/network_status_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_network_aware_app/ui/components/network_aware_widget.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Network Aware App"),
      ),
      body: StreamProvider<NetworkStatus>(
        create: (context) =>
            NetworkStatusService().networkStatusController.stream,
        child: NetworkAwareWidget(
          onlineChild: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "I am online",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          offlineChild: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                "No internet connection!",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey[400],
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see we are wrapping our `NetworkAwareWidget` inside a `StreamProvider` of `NetworkStatus`. StreamProvider also makes sure that on create it will subscribe to the NetworkStatusService controller stream.

Finally our app starting point `main.dart` will look something like this -

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_network_aware_app/ui/screens/home_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(primaryColor: Colors.blue),
        home: Home());
  }
}
```

The application would work as follows -

[image: Online Offline Demo]

I hope this helps you to build you own network aware app and components!

Comment: Package `connectivity` has been deprecated; you might want to update your answer to use `connectivity_plus`.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this alternative, without using any packages. Call this function whenever you need to check internet connectivity

```
Future<bool> internetConnectivity() async {
try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    return true;
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  return false;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: I tried this, using mobile data (I dont have internet acces); it still returns true because it is able to gather result from internetadress.lookup. Thanks tho

Comment: I guess you just have to lookup an address that's less pervasive than google

Answer (score 3):

You can use this https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_widget . By installing this package use this code in your build function.

```
ConnectivityWidget(
        builder: (context, isOnline) => Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("${isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: isOnline ? Colors.green : Colors.red),),
              SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Text(
                'Number of times we connected to the internet:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Does your solution checks the internet connectivity repeatedly?

Comment: I am using this widget but shows that i am offline even though i am online

Comment: Yes. It checks internet connectivity repeatedly. Can share your code?

Comment: I have used flutter_offline plugin and it worked. here is the link to my project repo  https://github.com/umakanth-pendyala/DO-List-APP-flutter.git. You don't have to go through the entire project just see lib/screens/connectivity_screen.dart. feel free to clone the project and implement your solution, and if it works please tell me

Answer (score 2):

[connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) package is just for discovering network connectivity. if you want to be sure about internet access you can use [data_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker).