# How to wait for internet connection in flutter application?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add functionality to my app where it waits on the load screen till the internet connection is available. Is there any way I can achieve this functionality.

Comment: Have you checked - https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity. This along with timer can solve your purpose.

Comment: I have seen the connectivity package. but what is this timmer?

Comment: Check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62610924/5387880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Flutter Favorite** package called [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity)

This package has a method where you can check if

- A user has an internet connection or not
- Whether the user is using mobile data or Wifi

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());

if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
  // I am not connected to any network.

} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.

} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  // I am connected to a wifi network.

}
```