# Check if connected to WiFi (even without internet) or Mobile data

Tags: flutter, dart, networking

I want to check if device is connected to WiFi or on Mobile Data, I am using [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity), but it times out when there is no Active Internet connection on WiFi, I want enable some functions if there is no Active connections but is still connected to any WiFi

Hope it clears my doubt,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hope can help you

> ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49648870/5588637

```dart
import 'dart:io';
...
try {
  final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
  if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
    print('connected');
  }
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  print('not connected');
}
```

Comment: Actually, what I want is to get the status of device WiFi, if it is connected to certain network it should be able to detect although the WiFi may or may not have an active Internet connection