# how to detect the device connectivity state while using firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using flutter with firebase, how can I know if my device is connected to the internet or not when I wanna make a query to firestore? if my device is offline what will firestore return ?, I must detect the device connectivity situation, so I can emit a certain state in my app.

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore SDK doesn't provide any way to know if the app is offline.  The SDK was designed to work while offline.  So, if you perform a query while offline, you will either get cached results, or the query will silently retry in the background.

If you want to test for connectivity, you will need [try another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app) to do that.  Or, you could use the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) (not the Flutter SDK) and detect if the query failed due to network problems.

Comment: thanks in advance, the resources did help me a lot.