# Is there a possibility to know the user's connection status through firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am developing a flutter application with the firebase database and I want to know if there is a possibility to know the internet connection status of the application user through firebees (not application  )
regards :)

Comment: You mean like this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state? Or like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app?