# How to check internet connectivity throughout the app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, internet-connection

I know how to check connectivity for single page. But I want to how I can Internet connectivity throughout all the pages in flutter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether there is an Internet connection available on Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app)

Comment: You can save use state-management to share the resource, in your case network status

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) plugin to check for network availability. Instead of checking for network on every screen, you can place the network checker on the class where network connectivity is needed i.e. the repository for http requests. With this approach, the network is checked when it's needed.