# constantly showing snackbar in case of no internet in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I check the internet status in my application and accordingly I run a snackbar and give information. But I want this snackbar not to go in the process where there is no internet, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a boolean variable that save if true or false your have internet and use if statement to check to show snack bar.

And for more understanding you can check out this post from stack overflow[Internet connect check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app)