# I want to check my app is connected with internet or not for complete app at once [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter

I got many solutions but there is no way to apply check internet is connected or not in complete flutter app. Please help to get out of it and let me know the solutions for checking its in one time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether there is an Internet connection available on Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app)

Comment: No.... i want internet check throughout the whole app in one time code.

Comment: You can set up a Stream listener. See the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56959146/12349734

Comment: Is there any way to check internet connectivity in all screens of app? I tried many solutions but have to check internet in each file. I want to check all files at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use internet connection checker [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker)

```
InternetConnectionChecker().checkInterval = Duration(seconds: 10);
      InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange.listen(
        (InternetConnectionStatus status) {
          switch (status) {
            case InternetConnectionStatus.connected:
              // ignore: avoid_print
              print('Data connection is available.');
              internetAvailable = true;
              setState(() {});
              break;
            case InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected:
              // ignore: avoid_print
              print('You are disconnected from the internet.');
              internetAvailable = false;
              setState(() {});
              break;
          }
        },
      );
```

Then based on the internetAvailable add the first screen

```
return internetAvailable? Center(child:Text("no internet")):HomePage()
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. By using this i have to add this in all widgets.  " return internetAvailable? Center(child:Text("no internet")):HomePage()  " right?

Comment: No you can use this in your main.dart and return the first screen

Comment: I have 4 apps and there are around 200+ screens. Is there any best way to add internet check in all screens in one time add.

Comment: If my app is on 4th page i off my net is that worked from there?

Comment: Yeah it will work. Since its listening from main.dart

Comment: Ok will try and let you know... thank you for the help.

Comment: Not working its just working for one screen on which i added.

Comment: Are you adding it in main.dart or in inner pages?

Comment: I tried adding in both files. For now i added this internet check in every screen. Will see later. BTW Thanks alot.

Comment: Please accept the answers if it helped so it will be useful for others

Comment: Not worked for me... i used connectivity and provider package.

Comment: In main. dart you are returning a material app.  Inside the material app you will be returning the first screen. In this place add the internet checker. If internet is available return the page or else a placeholder for no internet. It's working for me in all screens.

Comment: Yes i did the same..