# How to overlay a popup on top of MaterialApp navigator in a flutter App?

Tags: flutter, overlay, modular

In case of internet connectivity loss I want to show a widget which informs the user on connectivity issues. I want this widget to show when connectivity status changes, **no matter which route is present right now**.

The issue is that I can't find a way to overlay this "connectivity loss" widget on top of the main navigator (Used Modular for Navigation).

What's the best way to implement it?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app

Answer (score 0):

**create one provider for connectivity and listen it on all the screens**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

enum NetworkStatus { Online, Offline }

class NetworkStatusService {
  StreamController<NetworkStatus> networkStatusController =
      StreamController<NetworkStatus>();

  NetworkStatusService() {
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((status){
      networkStatusController.add(_getNetworkStatus(status));
    });
  }

  NetworkStatus _getNetworkStatus(ConnectivityResult status) {
    return status == ConnectivityResult.mobile || status == ConnectivityResult.wifi ? NetworkStatus.Online : NetworkStatus.Offline;
  }
}
```

**in the build method of all the screens.**

```
 NetworkStatus networkStatus = Provider.of<NetworkStatus>(context);
    if (networkStatus == NetworkStatus.Online) {
      return realscreen();
    } else {
      _showToastMessage("Offline");
      return offlineimagewidget();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not looking to repeat it in all screen, it needs to overlay on top of all screens.

Comment: then create one screen and pass all the widgets as a child in that screen simply.

Comment: I'm using Modular for navigation

Answer (score 0):

I used a method like the one below in my own application. You can adapt it to your own project

```
void goToPage() async {
    var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (request) {
      request = !request;
      try {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient();
        httpClient.connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: 5);
        HttpClientRequest req =
            await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url + "/get-counts"));
        HttpClientResponse resp =
            await req.close().timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        String jsonStr = await utf8.decodeStream(resp);
        dynamic jsonDyn = json.decode(jsonStr);
        await prefs.setString(
            "text", jsonDyn["data"]["text"]);
        await prefs.setString("text",
            jsonDyn["data"]["text"]);
        await prefs.setString("text", jsonDyn["data"]["text"]);

        await prefs.setString(
            "text", jsonDyn["data"]["text"]);
        
        if (prefs.getString("hash") != null) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(FadePageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DashboardScreen(
                analytics: widget.analytics, observer: widget.observer),
          ));
        } else {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(FadePageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LoginScreen(
                  analytics: widget.analytics, observer: widget.observer)));
        }
      } catch (e) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext builderContext) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                child: AlertDialog(
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  actions: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: const Color(0xFFFCCBD8),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          request = !request;
                          goToPage();
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: const [
                            Text("Try Again",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF6953A0),
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          ],
                        ))
                  ],
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF6953A0),
                  title: Icon(
                    Icons.signal_wifi_connected_no_internet_4_outlined,
                    size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                    color: const Color(0xFFFCCBD8),
                  ),
                  content: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text("Check Your Internet Connection.",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFFCCBD8))),
                        )
                      ]),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [overlayment](https://pub.dev/packages/overlayment) to do this.

This will show an overlay without carrying on which route you are.
You can show this as [notification](https://pub.dev/packages/overlayment#overnotification), or you can use `Overlayment.showMessage(connectionMessage)`.

See the [online demo](https://overlayment.netlify.app/#/)