# internet listen on every screen flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to check the internet on every page in my flutter app how I can do that without repeating the same code on every screen?
here is my code

```
bool internet = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    countryController.text = "+961";
    Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((connectionState) {
      if (connectionState == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        setState(() {
          internet = false;
        });
        // valueNotifierBook.incrementNotifier();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          internet = true;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: You can review this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app