# Check internet connection status

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for the best way to check if the device is connected to Internet from a Flutter iOS and Android app. [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) isn't enough, as stated in the officiale documentation:

> Note that on Android, this does not guarantee connection to Internet. For instance, the app might have wifi access but it might be a VPN or a hotel WiFi with no access.

I also found an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app) suggesting some "hand-made" workaround, but the thread is far too old as we are in 2023 now. Are there any new method to check for the connection status? How do you handle it in your apps?

Comment: just use http and test internet connection as described in this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/74411817/10853095)in the old question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app) you have found.

Comment: Is it better than the most voted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49648870/19290739)?

Comment: yes cuz the `http` call will not cache stuff like `InternetAddress`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether there is an Internet connection available on Flutter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app)

Comment: Why not just try to use internet right away and catch the error if it fails? Since internet connection is inherently unreliable you must do this anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Using the package [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker/install) you can check the connection status of devices (accurate for iOS/android I believe, and flaky for other stuff, so I just return `true` for other platforms in my code so that I don't miss a call because I assume they don't have connection when they actually do).

Here is an example implementation which you can call from anywhere in your code:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';

abstract class INetworkInfo {
  Future<bool> get isConnected;
}

// Checks if the current device can connect to the internet (iOS and Android only).
class NetworkInfo implements INetworkInfo {
  final InternetConnectionChecker connectionChecker;

  NetworkInfo(this.connectionChecker);

  /// Returns TRUE if the current device has an internet connection. Returns FALSE if the device doesn't.
  ///
  /// Returns TRUE by default for platforms that aren't iOS or Android.
  @override
  Future<bool> get isConnected async => Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS
      ? await connectionChecker.hasConnection
      : true;
}
```

Just call `isConnected` to check if you have a connection.

Comment: this package currently not continued.  you can find maintaining and modified version of this package https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker_plus

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker) package in conjunction with  [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus). The internet_connection_checker documentation mentions a simple example of how to do that [here](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker#purpose). This works by pinging a list of common DNS providers, and will work as expected if you're connected to WiFi that's not connected to the internet, like printer WiFi or a network that you haven't signed into. This way you don't have to deal with writing HTTP tests yourself!

Remember that it's still important to account for timeouts and bad connections, such as if you're connected to the internet but the server you're trying to reach is offline.

**Side Note:**
The [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648022/check-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-flutter-app) you linked to mentions [data_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker), which looks like an old version of internet_connection_checker. It isn't under active development (the last update was in 2019) so I wouldn't use it.